# why this type of If-statement gives true in CPP

Tags: c++, if-statement

why this type of expression gives true in cpp; a<=b<=c, even b not in range(a,b)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    if(2<=14<=10){
        cout<<1;
    }
}

output:1
```

Comment: `2<=14<=10` expands to `(2 <= 14) <= 10`. `(2 <= 14)` is `true`. When evaluating `true <= 10`, the compiler promotes `true` to an `int` to make the comparison, so it becomes `1 <= 10`, which is `true`.

Comment: @NathanPierson that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau By the time I had written this up as an aswer, the question was already closed as a duplicate. I still wanted to leave the comment to expand on how the duplicate applies to this particular code.